# Why doesn't .toUpperCase() capitalize str[i]?

Tags: javascript, indexing, capitalization

Doing a CoderByte challenge:

> Using the JavaScript language, have the function LetterChanges(str)
>   take the str parameter being passed and modify it using the following
>   algorithm. Replace every letter in the string with the letter
>   following it in the alphabet (ie. c becomes d, z becomes a). Then
>   capitalize every vowel in this new string (a, e, i, o, u) and finally
>   return this modified string.

my solution:

```
function LetterChanges(str) {
    var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza",
        vowels = "aiueo",
        newstr = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (alphabet.indexOf(str[i]) != -1) {
            newstr += alphabet[alphabet.indexOf(str[i]) + 1];
        } else {
            newstr += str[i];
        }  
    }


    for (var i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < newstr.length; j++) {
            //toUppercase the vowel in the newstring once found
            if (newstr[j] == vowels[i]) {
                newstr[j] = newstr[j].toUpperCase(); 
            }
        }
   }
   return newstr;
} 

show(LetterChanges("fun times"));
show(LetterChanges("hello*3"));
```

The `toUpperCase()` does not capitalize the vowel I want. It seems correct though. I've even tried something like this:

```
if (newstr[j] == vowels[i]) {
   var toCap = newstr[j].toString();
   newstr[j] = toCap.toUpperCase();
}
```

If you think of a better solution, then please answer the `toUpperCase()` part and then recommend another solution.

Comment: For the vowels uppercase part, you could use a regular expression and call `newstr = newstr.replace()` on the string, like `.replace(/[aeiou]+/g, function (match) { return match.toUpperCase(); });`

Comment: @Ian you should provide this as an answer since it solves the problem.

Comment: It seems the challenge text is purposefully setting up the user for a failure.

Comment: These are some correct example input and outputs. Input = `"hello*3"`Output = `"Ifmmp*3"`
Input = `"fun times!"`Output = `"gvO Ujnft!"`

Comment: I saw other solutions and found another bug with this code. If the input has a capitalized letter in it, then the output is incorrect.

Comment: To correct it `var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzaABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA"`

Answer (score 2):

Strings in Javascript are primitive types, not objects.

When you set a property in a primitive type (eg, `str[i] = 'a'`), Javascript creates a new boxed object for that value, mutates it, then throws it away.

For more details, see the [spec](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1).

Instead, you should assemble the new string in a mutable array, then call `.join('')` to convert it to a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can create another string to build the return string, see bellow a fix in your code

```
function LetterChanges(str) {
    var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza",
        vowels = "aiueo",
        newstr = '',
        returnStr = ''; //added to next step

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (alphabet.indexOf(str[i]) != -1) {
            newstr += alphabet[alphabet.indexOf(str[i]) + 1];
        } else {
            newstr += str[i];
        }  
    }


    for (var i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < newstr.length; j++) {
            //toUppercase the vowel in the newstring once found
            if (newstr[j] == vowels[i]) {
                returnStr += newstr[j].toUpperCase(); 
            }else{
                returnStr += newstr[j];
            }
        }
   }
   return returnStr ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capitalize the vowels via `replace` and an uppercasing function:

```
newstr = newstr.replace(
           /[aeiou]/g,           // replace all vowels
           function(letter) {    // called for each match
             return letter.toUpperCase();
           }
         );
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/tvhcF

Comment: This is my first time seeing something like /[aeiou]/g. That's regex right? How would that be read?

Comment: `[aeiou]`: match any of the letters between the brackets. `/g` means do this repeatedly; otherwise we'd just match and replace the first vowel we found.

Comment: @Patrick https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions The whole MDN website is great for learning

Answer (score 0):

The contents of a string cannot be changed, I.E. they are immutable. Create a new string instead of trying to edit one in-place.

Comment: Could I add the new letters to an array. Change items in the array. then join them into a string?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with this problem.  @Patrick is replacing the array's element with the string that is returned from the `toUpperCase` method so the array should hold the new reference to the string.

Comment: @Justin What array? There is not a single array in the entire code.

Comment: @Esailija Sorry, seeing the square brakets made me focus on arrays lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your life easy with the following code

```
     function LetterChanges(str) { 

    return str.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,function(x) {
    return String.fromCharCode(x.charCodeAt(0)+1); }).replace(/[aeiou]/g,function(y) {
    return y.toUpperCase(); 
    });

  }
```